# Find the first name that starts with any letter than S using regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am new to regex and I am trying to find the last names that only start with S followed by comma and then space and then the first names that doesn't start with S from a text file.
I am using the terminal on a MacBook.

This is my regex

```
^[S\w][,]?[' ']?[A-RT-Z]?
```

**My full command**

> cat People.txt | grep -E ^[S\w][,]?[' ']?[A-RT-Z]?

**The *first name* is the second word and the *last name* is the first word on each line.**

The results I get:

> Schmidt, Paul
>
> Sells, Simon
>
> Smith, Peter
>
> Stephens, Sheila

What I am expecting to get

> Schmidt, Paul
>
> Smith, Peter

Comment: Are you using `grep` or `awk` or `sed` or `perl` or `python` or `ed` or something else?  Which options with `grep` if it is `grep`?  It would be best to show the command line you're using.  The repeated single quotes in the character class are nominally irrelevant (a character class `[aba]` is the same as `[ab]`).  But single quotes (and double quotes) are important in the shell.  The `\w` notation has a special meaning in PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions), but not elsewhere.

Comment: I am using grep. This is my full command:: cat People.txt | grep -E ^[S\w][,]?[' ']?[A-RT-Z]?

Comment: Please review [UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) — and use `grep -E '…regex…' People.txt` to process the file.  Note that my outline encloses the whole regex in single quotes — this is strongly recommended as it prevents unwanted shell expansions/processing of metacharacters.  You then would not need the interior single quotes around the space.  You don't need a character class around the comma (though it doesn't do major harm).  As written, your regex looks for lines starting with `S` or `w` (the shell removes the backslash for you).

Comment: The command line you edited into the question doesn't match the command line shown in your comment.  Is either of them accurate?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually it works know fine. Thanks for the link you give it to me it was very helpful. The one in the comments is the accurate one I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of writing regular expressions in a shell script (or at the terminal) is "enclose the regular expression in single quotes" so that the shell doesn't try to interpret the metacharacters in the regex.  You might sometimes use double quotes instead of single quotes if you need to match single quotes but not double quotes or if you need to interpolate a variable, but aim to use single quotes.  Also, avoid [UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Your question currently shows two regular expressions:

```
^[S\w][,]?[' ']?[A-RT-Z]?

cat People.txt | grep -E ^[S\w][,]?[' ']?[P\w+]?
```

If written as suggested, these would become:

```
grep -E -e '^[Sw],? ?[A-RT-Z]?' People.txt
grep -E -e '^[Sw],? ?[Pw+]?' People.txt
```

The shell removes the backslashes in your rendition.  The `+` in the character class matches a plus sign.  You don't need square brackets around the comma (though they do no major harm).  I use the `-e` option for explicitness, and so I can add extra arguments after the regex (`-w` or `-l` or `-n` or …) when editing commands via history.  (I also dislike having options recognized after non-option arguments; I often run with `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` set in my environment.  That's a personal quirk.)

The first of the two commands looks for a line starting `S` or `w`, followed by an optional comma, an optional blank, and an optional upper-case letter other than `S`.  The second is similar except that it looks for an optional `P` or `w`.  None of this bears much relationship to the question.

You need an expression more like one of these:

```
grep -E -e '^[S][[:alpha:]]*, [^S]' People.txt
grep -E -e '^[S][a-zA-Z]*, [^S]' People.txt
```

These allow single-character names — just `S` — but you can use `+` instead of `*` to require one or more letters.

There are lots of refinements possible, depending on how much you want to work, but this does the primary job of finding 'first word on the line starts with `S`, and is followed by a comma, a blank, and the second word does not start with `S`'.

Given a file `People.txt` containing:

```
Randall, Steven
Rogers, Timothy
Schmidt, Paul
Sells, Simon
Smith, Peter
Stephens, Sheila
Titus, Persephone
Williams, Shirley
Someone
S
```

Your regular expressions produce the output:

```
Schmidt, Paul
Sells, Simon
Smith, Peter
Stephens, Sheila
Someone
S
```

My commands produce:

```
Schmidt, Paul
Smith, Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work fine:

```perl
^S.*, [^S].*$
```

- `^S.*` - must start with S and start capturing everything
- `, [^S]` - leading up to a comma, space, not S
- `.*$` - capture the rest of the string

https://regex101.com/r/76bfji/1

Comment: I am writing it like this in the terminal and I am still getting the same results  grep -E ^[S.*,][^S].*$ People.txt. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: @KarimOsama Why aren't you using the regex I provided?

Comment: I tried again without brackets as you wrote and it is working fine.THANKS